# Is it possible to loop through an enum to add every item to a list in java?

Tags: java, list, enums

I have an enum with 30 values and I need to put each one into a list. Is there a way to loop over each one and add them vs having 30 lines of code adding each one? The enum name is School and I tried doing something like

```
 List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
 schools.add(School.values());
```

and

```
List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
 schools.addAll(School.values());
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry I fixed it

Comment: there is no difference between the two codes

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ no it says it is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: @user3887792 Added my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your List like

```
List<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>(Arrays.asList(School.values()));
```

If you use  `Arrays.asList(School.values())`  , you cannot add anything to that list later and you'll end up with an Exception. From docs of  [`asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

If you create the way suggested, you are able to add further elements to it.

Answer (score 1):

`enum#values` returns an array. Use `Arrays.asList` instead:

```
schools.add(Arrays.asList(School.values()));
```

Or one-line:

```
List<School> schools = Arrays.asList(School.values());
```

Comment: (In case of second line): So OP cannot add anything afterwards to `schools`.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ that's why I show first option. Anyway, I cannot think on an explicit use case where you would need to add repeated enum values into a `List<YourEnum>` so one-line approach will suffice this time.

Comment: Agreed. I edited my comment with line no.